# How to search an subitem text for all items in listview? vb.net

Tags: vb.net, listview

I have a listview that can contain two types of items, depends on subitem(3).text, if subitem(3).text has "off" then item should not be send through serial port and if it contains numeric value it should be send. I want to make code that can search all items with "numeric values" in subitem(3).text, then combine them in one string, after that, send the string. So the problem is to serach that items with "numeric value" in subitem(3) in listview2 control.
This is how im searching an items now:

```
 Private Sub Button8_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles 
    Button8.Click
    If ListView2.Items.Count.Equals(0) And ListView2.Items(0).SubItems(3).Text <> "off" Then
         GetValueFromlv2Row = "434D4430" & ListView2.FocusedItem.SubItems(0).Text & dlc_case & data_to_send
    ' test it with some bytes, with some optional spaces in the string
    Dim myBytes = MyStringConversions.StringToByteArray(GetValueFromlv2Row)
    spObj.Write(myBytes, 0, myBytes.Length)
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: If you want to examine all items then it should be obvious that you need to start with a loop. I suggest that you try that and then post back if and when you get stuck. It should be very easy to find examples of looping through all items in a `ListView`, if you can't come up with the code yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With @Jmcilhinney help, i managed to solve it. For them who having the same problem, the code is below:

```
For i = 0 To ListView2.Items.Count - 1
            If ListView2.Items(i).SubItems(4).Text <> "off" Then   'checking subitem for and nu,eric value
               'YOUR CODE HERE
               ' YOUR CODE HERE
         end if
  end select
```